# Header image not resizing on mobile safari, -- remains completely zoomed out

Tags: html, ios, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

The header image in my Rails generated bootstrap'ed webpage resizes correctly with Chrome/firefox/Opera but not with Mobile Safari. I've got the following meta tags in the header

```
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Here's the HTML and CSS:

```
<!-- This is the Html -->
<div class="section section-fill-height">
  <div class="background-image background-image-fixed" style="background-image : url('sample1.jpg')"></div>
 </div>

 /* And this is the CSS  */
 .section {
 position:relative;
  }

  .section-fill-height {
  display: flex;
  height:100%;        
  align-items: center;
   }

   .section .background-image {
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    }

    .section .background-image.background-image-fixed {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: Please show us the html/css of your image. Mobile Safari has some issues with, for example, background images and background-attachment:fixed. But without seeing your html/css, there is not much we can do to help.

Comment: Hi @SuneS.-T.  OK, I added the html and css to the above. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I added an answer below based on your posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mobile Safari, you have to set the background image to `background-attachment: scroll`. Background images with `background-attachment: fixed` will not show properly in Mobile Safari. Mobile Safari cannot use `background-size: cover` in combination with `background-attachment: fixed`, since Mobile Safari does not resize the background image, the way you would expect of it (the way other browsers do).

The following is probably not the best solution, but it works:
In your javascript (jQuery), do this:

```
/*===============================================================
  Various fixes for mobile devices
===============================================================*/

 /* Detect if mobile device */
(function(a){(jQuery.browser=jQuery.browser||{}).mobile=/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);

if(jQuery.browser.mobile){
    /* Adjust body class */
    $("body").addClass("mobile-fix");
}
```

And in your CSS:

```
body.mobile-fix .section .background-image.background-image-fixed {
background-attachment: scroll !important;
}
```